# In October: "nel" vs "in"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which would be the better way to say "**in October**"?
Here is what I am trying to say in English;
**I did not know a word of Italian in October.**

1) Non sapevo una parola di italiano **nel mese di ottobre**.
2) Non sapevo una parola di italiano **in ottobre**.

Are they both correct?
If so, which is better; "***nel o in***"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the second one is wrong, but surely it is less used. The first one sounds better and is more usual.

An alternative would be:

> Non sapevo una parola di italiano ***ad*** ottobre,

(where an euphonic *d* could be added, but see the comments below).

Comment: Hmmm.... I'm going to have to look THAT up!  ;-)

Comment: Are you sure about the euphonic *d*, mrnld? The most usual rule of the thumb is to use it only when two equal vowels meet: *ed Enrico* but *e Andrea*.

Comment: @DaG you're right: it is not *necessary*, but it's more like [a personal choice](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/A/a-ad.shtml). Also, there are [several examples](https://www.google.it/search?q=ad+ottobre&client=ms-android-google&biw=360&bih=249&prmd=niv&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV_ZOFyNzKAhUHv3IKHXZUCpwQ_AUICygG) of its use.

Answer (score 4):

In Italian, time determinations are often at the beginning of a sentence.

Hence, in my opinion, by far the most natural way of expressing your idea would be:

> *A ottobre non sapevo una parola di italiano*.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is wrong. I mean can, and is used, but is not correct.

- Non sapevo niente **ad** Ottobre.
- **In/Ad** Ottobre cadono le foglie.

**In** refers to something that is happening or it used to happen within that time period.