# Preposizioni semplici: IN oppure A con i mesi dell'anno?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Salve a tutti,
domanda veloce :)

Quando è corretto usare A e quando IN con i mesi dell'anno?

“A gennaio nevica sempre” o “In gennaio nevica sempre”?

C'è una regola?

Comment: Non so se considerarlo proprio un doppione, ma se ne parlava anche qui: http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/in-october-nel-vs-in

Comment: io direi "a gennaio...", "in gennaio..." mi suona assai strano... però sto ancora imparando la lingua, forse non mi è mai capitato di sentire "in".

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: @DaG, per conto mio è praticamente un doppio.

Comment: Non è proprio un doppio: nella domanda del link  "ottobre" è un ben determinato ottobre; qui invece si parla di gennaio come mese dell'anno. Non sono sicuro che ciò comporti una differenza. L'analogo per i giorni della settimana invece sì: 
"venerdì (questo venerdì) sono stato dal dottore" mentre:

"il dottore riceve il venerdì / di venerdì"

Comment: Se ne parla anche in questa domanda e nella sua risposta: http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5194/sulluso-delle-maiuscole-e-le-preposizioni-con-i-nomi-dei-mesi (doppione?). Se ho capito bene la risposta, tutte e due le preposizioni sono corrette anche nella frase di questa domanda. È così?

Comment: to me in seems almost always just wrong maybe with the exception of "ottobre" and would think only a is correct...

Answer (score 1):

The form with "a" can certainly be used in sentences referring to the future like "arrivederci a gennaio", and also sometimes in reference to the past, as in "a dicembre nevicava". Note however that the form with "in" can be used as well in both examples.

The form with "in" seems dominant when referring to a date within a certain month ("il giorno dell'Epifania è in gennaio"), or when referring to a precise event within a month, as in "sono nato in dicembre".

So I would say that the two forms are not completely interchangeable: while "in" can replace "a" in most cases (but not all: "rimandato a settembre" looks like an exception), the form with "a" seems to have a much more limited application.

Comment: Please, note that  here we have the policy of answering in English to a question posted in English and in Italian to a question posted in Italian, so could you please write your answer in Italian?

Answer (score 1):

"A" è preferibile in quasi tutti i contesti, seppure "in" sia corretto in molti casi.

Esempio con in:

> Questo avvenimento è accaduto in gennaio.

Altrettanto corretto è l'uso di "a" in questo stesso caso.

Il *vice versa* non è spesso vero, per esempio:

> Ho rimandato il tutto a Gennaio.

non può essere resa con "in".

Answer (score -1):

"In" gennaio è sicuramente la forma italiana più comune (almeno quando vuole semplicemente rappresentare un complemento di tempo).

La forma "a" gennaio sottintende quasi sempre un metaforico moto a luogo, come nell'espressione scolastica, una volta assai consueta, "rimandato a settembre", che si diceva di un allievo che non aveva ottenuto direttamente la promozione a fine anno, e quindi doveva sostenere degli esami di riparazione subito prima della ripresa dei corsi.

(Aggiungo, anche tenendo conto delle osservazioni espresse da altri utenti, che la scelta tra l'una e l'altra preposizione potrebbe pure essere determinata principalmente da usi regionali. Io sono del Nordest, e quella che riferisco è in parte la preferenza della mia zona di appartenenza.)

Segnalo che [un articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca](http://www-old.accademiadellacrusca.it/faq/faq_risp.php%3Fid=7396&ctg_id=93.html) indicherebbe una sostanziale indifferenza nell'uso di a/in davanti al nome del mese.

Comment: “è sicuramente la forma italiana più comune”: fonte? È una tua impressione o conosci qualche studio in proposito?

Comment: @DaG È una mia impressione, fondata sul fatto che l'italiano è la mia lingua madre.

Comment: Anche la mia e anche quella di molti altri, ma purtroppo non sempre è sufficiente, così come non siamo tutti cardiologi per il fatto di avere un cuore. A me, per esempio, suona più naturale “a”, mentre riserverei “in” a contesti più formali, e come vedi altri italiani qui sopra hanno opinioni discordanti.